# Can live updates in Smartsheet, reflect in the Power BI Service reports?

Tags: powerbi, smartsheet-api

In summary, 
Can live updates in **Smartsheets**, reflect in the **Power BI** Service reports.

Here are the details:
1. We added the **Smartsheets** app via the **GetApp** feature of Power BI Service. 
It shows the total number of sheets in **Smartsheets**, but not the individual sheets from which i can get the data!

2. We have already connected **Smartsheet** to **Power BI Desktop** and the data is being pulled from **Smartsheets** to **Power Bi** Desktop and we can publish it manually to **Power Bi Service**.

We want a report built and get live data or at least frequent scheduled refreshes of the hourly updated **Smartsheets**.

We checked this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-connect-to-smartsheet

and it says what i've written above...:
" The Smartsheet template app for Power BI provides a dashboard, reports, and dataset that show an overview of your Smartsheet account. You can also use Power BI Desktop to connect directly to individual sheets in your account."

So basically, we are stuck with just an overview of our Smartsheet account connected to Power BI Service. This shows the useless information of total number of Smartsheets , and not the individual Smartsheets themselves.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Smartsheet Live Data Connector as a data source for Power BI. 
It is an ODBC compliant data source that you can load all of your sheet data into Power BI with. https://www.smartsheet.com/marketplace/apps/live-data-connector

Power BI has schedule refresh functionality:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/refresh-scheduled-refresh

If you are feeling frisky you can use a Smartsheet Webhook to trigger the update for real time updates. 
http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#intro-to-webhooks

Answer (score 1):

The short and direct answer is "yes, it can."

For any specific Power BI dashboard, the specific sheets (or reports*) must be selected for whatever is going to be displayed.

I suggest using REPORTS as the data source for most things I have displayed in dashboards.

If I recall, there is a way to have Power BI refresh periodically (my usage is about a year old as everything just ... worked)

Craig

Comment: Hi Crag, Thank you.
Yes, For dashboards, our data sources are Reports . The dashboards update themselves, when the Reports are refreshed.

However, the data source in the Report, which is Smartsheet in our case, needs a manual refresh from Power BI Desktop.
I'd like to know if this can be an automatic data refresh and what are the steps to make it happen.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found a free and easy solution that worked right away.  I used Power Automate.  2 steps.

1. When row created (or updated should work too)
2. Refresh dataset.

Image of Power Automate flow:
[image: Image of Power Automate flow]